# Unable to use bluetooth

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth, services

Bluetooth service is running

```
sudo service bluetooth status
bluetooth start/running, process 1009
```

However, when I start bluetooth manager, it says there is no device and seems like bluetooth is disabled or something is wrong.

Also:

```
hcitool dev
Devices:
```

What's up with it?

As you can see, all buttons are disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't make the other advice "visible". This is done by searching in Bluetooth-preferences of your advice, afterwards Ubuntu will find it, when you press "search". That is for protection.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: visibility is set to on.

Comment: I mean visibility of your advice. Maybe it helps to switch also Ubuntu visibility on. Then "configure new advice" (or something like this) and search.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: This depends on your device. For example for a Celular phone, you might search in Blootooth-settings, system settings, or preferences. If you don't find anything contact your provider, or search on their internet page.

Comment: If it doesn't work to switch the buttons on, maybe your computer doesn't have Bluetooth.